# min-height 100% stretch

Tags: html, height, css

I have a problem with my min-height and height properties.

http://nickhellemans.be/nick/testing/

The blue column isn't going till the end of the page when the content is larger then 100%. (the full screen)

**HTML**

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <section id="sidebar">
        test
        </section>
        <section  class="contentViewer">
             content goes here
        </section>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

section#sidebar {
float:left;
width:300px;
min-height:100%;
height: auto !important;
margin: auto;
background-color: blue;
overflow: hidden;
}

section.contentViewer {
height:auto;
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
left:300px;
font-family: "brandon";
font-size:18pt;
}
```

I already tried to google it, but I wasn't able to find an answer that suits the problem. Someone familiar with this problem and knows a correct solution ?

Thanks in advance

Nick

Comment: Ahh the old 100% height conundrum. http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (again haha)

You will have to avoid float and absolute positioning since your parents don't scale along with absolute positioned child-elements. Because they don't scale along, they will default to 100%. I recommend using table structures (left column, right column, vertical align top width: 100% etc)

```
body, html, #wrapper { height: 100%; } /* defaults to 100% height */
#wrapper { display: table; }
#wrapper > * { display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; height: 100%; } /* Behave as tablecells */
#sidebar { background-color: blue; min-width: 200px; } /* min-width is important since other cell is 100% */
.contentViewer { background-color: red; width: 100%; } /* Fill up remaining space */
.container { position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%; } /* Use containers for relative positioning '*/


<div id="wrapper">
  <section id="sidebar">
    <div class="container">
      <p>Left side</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section  class="contentViewer">
    <div class="container">
      <p>Yoopie</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

The above code is my basic structure for a 2 column layout using css tables. It allowes for fluid design while still beiing able to use relative positioning. Normaly table-cells don't support position: relative; So I always use a .container div as a direct child-element of a table-cell

Comment: Thanks guys for the fast answers, removing the height rule didn't solve the problem. Now looking into Leeish blog post.

Comment: Tried your solution

http://nickhellemans.be/nick/testing/

Am i missing something ?

Comment: Yup, there was something wrong about the absolute positioning. I know what you are trying to accomplish though so I made you an example of a working layout using a left and right side with 100% or more height. Another nice effect is that they will never overlap and always stay next to eachother :)

Comment: Your solution worked ! It took a time to implement because I already animated some things with jquery and the display:table-cells messed it up. 

this was the result I tried to achieve http://nickhellemans.be/nick/

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I'm glad it worked, but can you please accept the answer? It might be helpfull to others and it is also helpfull for me since I get points (hihi) :)